# Derivation of eq 6.17, Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I am having trouble following a derivation in Peskin and Schroeder's textbook, namely equation 6.17 on page 182. It seems benign at first, but I am completely stuck. Essentially, we have an expression of the form 
$$
\quad\log\frac{(E^2-\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{p'})^2}{E^2(E-|\mathbf{p}|)^2} = 2\log\frac{p\cdot p'}{E(E-|\mathbf{p}|)}\tag{1}
$$ 
If I am not mistaken (note that we are in a reference frame defined such that $E'= E$ ). However, they then manipulate this into 
$$
\quad\approx2\log\frac{p\cdot p'}{\frac{E^2-\mathbf{p}^2}{2}} = 2\log\left(\frac{-q^2}{m^2}\right),\tag{2}
$$ 
with $q^2 \equiv (p-p')^2$. I don't understand either of these last two lines. How does the denominator simplify? And what is going in the final simplification? $q^2 = (2m^2 - 2p\cdot p')$, if I am not mistaken, which leaves me at a loss. I guess one might say in the extreme relativistic limit we can neglect the mass in the numerator and then then last step makes sense, but then it would seem that P&S should have placed an approximation sign in between the two terms in line (2). But still, the denominator simplification boggles me, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, there are just so many errors in the way how you "copied" it. First of all, the disk should be a simple dot, the 3D inner product. Second, the $E-\vec p$ should be simply $E-p$, it is nonsense to subtract a vector from a scalar. Third, second powers are heavily missing above $E$ and $p$ in your formulae, much like factors of 2. Also, the first $=$ should actually be just $\approx$, approximately equal. I don't recommend anyone going through this question before at least 80% of these bugs are fixed. It's a mess.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tips. What do you mean by "heavily missing"? And I don't think an approximation is needed in the first line. I just took down the square of the log argument and used the definition of a 4 vector dot product, where I should have mentioned that both p and p' are defined to have the same energy

Answer (score 3):

Eh nevermind, I figured it out. $(E^2-|\mathbf{p}|^2) = (E+|\mathbf{p}|)(E-|\mathbf{p}|)\approx2E(E-|\mathbf{p}|)$ when E is very close to $|\mathbf{p}|$ (considering that the term is in the denominator), which is the limit we are making the approximation in. And it seems like the last equality in line two was probably a typo in P&S, and should have been an approximation.